# DD-WRT calling web service from Arduino ESP8266

Tags: linux, router, python, dd-wrt, c

I am looking for a way of finding out what devices are currently attached wirelessly to the router thats running DD-WRT firmware.

Problem is that I am unable to find any references to a **REST API** or just a standard **HTTP API**.

I did, however, find something [HERE](https://www.milesburton.com/DD-WRT_Web-services#Status_Wireless) that stated theirs a page **Status_Wireless.live.asp** that shows some information but again, have not found any more information other than just the text about it. It also seems to need authorization in order to display anything on the page once there which would be hard to accomplish.

Does anyone have a screenshot or commands in order to do this with a DD-WRT firmware? More so, how I can accomplish logging into the page from the Arduino since it needs authorization. I will be using an **Arduino** with a ESP8266 that's connected to the router so in order to get the information i'll need to be able to get it with **http** so I can then parse the information I would be in need of within the Arduino code.

Answer (score 0):

DD-WRT does not use ASP (it would seem strange, right, to use Microsoft's stuff on a FOSS project), but it does not use PHP either. Actually, asp extensions are a misnomer: dd-wrt uses CGI (and regular C) in its Web pages. You can confirm it by reading [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=63715&sid=726b1147a695d5f2dee66196776b63fb), or just by perusing each Web page source code.

As such, I am aware of no API available to outside users, which in a way stands to reason: you need authentication to gain access to the router's data. Also, I know of no way to circumvent authentication. Best I can think of is parsing wget's output.